# How to print lists in a scific order in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

im working on a project and i have a list in kotlin like:

```
val list = listOf("banana", "1","apple","3","banana","2")
```

and i want to print it like

```
Output:
banana = 1
banana = 2
apple = 3
```

so like every work with the number should be like one val, and i need to print in scific order (the order is toooo random for any sort command), so im panning on just coppying the whole xinhua dictionary here (since all chinese words have a scific unicode), and make the code it replace like:

```
val list = listOf("banana丨", "1","apple丩","3","banana丨","2")
```

but how to print them in the order?

ps. even me as a chinese dont know most of the words in xinhua dictionary lol so there is more then enofe

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the following input list, as shown in your question, where the order of occurrence is always one word followed by the scific order:

```kotlin
val list = listOf("banana", "1","apple","3","banana","2")
```

You could do the following:

**1. Create a `data class` that defines one entry in your raw input list**

```kotlin
data class WordEntry(val word: String, val order: Int)
```

**2. Map over your raw input list by using the `windowed` and `map` methods**

```kotlin
val dictionary = list.windowed(2, 2).map { WordEntry(it.first(), it.last().toInt()) }
```

Here, the `windowed(2, 2)` method creates a window of size 2 and step 2, meaning that we iterate over the raw input list and always work with two entries at every second step. Assuming that the order in the raw input list is always the word followed by the scific order, this should work. Otherwise, this would not work, so the order is very important here!

**3. Sort the transformed `dictionary` by the `order` property**

```kotlin
val sortedDictionary = dictionary.sortedBy { it.order }
```

Edit: You can also sort by any other property. Just pass another property to the lambda expression of `sortedBy` (e.g. `sortedBy { it.word }` if you want to sort it by the `word` property)

**4. Finally, you can print out your sorted dictionary**

```kotlin
val outputStr = sortedDictionary.joinToString("\n") { "${it.word} = ${it.order}" }

print(outputStr)
```

Output:

```
banana = 1
banana = 2
apple = 3
```

Comment: Note that `windowed(2, 2)` is just `chunked(2)`.

Comment: but i want it to be sorted by the words not the numbers 

Comment: @cyao1234 Step 3 does the sorting and expains how it does. It should be straightforward to change it to sort by the word instead of the order :-)

Comment: @mattfreake oh om thank you

Comment: As @mattfreake already mentioned, you only have to change the sorting behavior. I have edited my answer to include an example